# Copy file using javascript client object model - new version

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, versioning, file

I have a solution that adds a custom button to the ribbon in SharePoint 2010 and am using the javascript client object model behind the scenes to copy a file from Library A to Library B when the button is pressed. The copy works fine but instead of adding the file as a new version in Library B (if the file exists there already), the file in Library B is just overwritten and the version remains at v1.0.

I have:

- versioning turned on in Library B
- the javascript performs a check-out of the file in Library B and then performs the copy

Is there something I'm missing?  Has anybody accomplished this before?  Is this not possible via the Javascript CSOM in SharePoint 2010?

Code:

```
var _ctx;
var _sourceFile;
var _destinationlibUrl;
var _destinationFile;

// LibraryA is the name of the 'source' Document Library
// LibraryB is the name of the 'destination' Document Library

function CopyFile() {

    // Get the current client context of the client-side object model (CSOM) runtime.
    _ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    // Get the Web site that is associated with the client context.
    this.web = _ctx.get_web();
    _ctx.load(this.web);

    // Returns the list with the specified title from the collection.
    this.sourceList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('LibraryA');
    _ctx.load(this.sourceList);

    // Get the list items being selected.
    var selectedDocuments = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(_ctx);
    this.currentItem = sourceList.getItemById(selectedDocuments[0].id);
    _ctx.load(this.currentItem);

    // Get the file that is represented by the item from a document library.
    _sourceFile = this.currentItem.get_file();
    _ctx.load(_sourceFile);

    _ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

// Delegate that is called when the query completes successfully.
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    if (_sourceFile != null) {
        _destinationlibUrl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() +
                            '/LibraryB/' + 
                            _sourceFile.get_name();

        // Get hold of the file in the destination library.
        _destinationFile = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_destinationlibUrl);
        _ctx.load(_destinationFile);

        _ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onLoadSucceeded),
                               Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

// Delegate that is called when the destination file checkout completes successfully.
function onLoadSucceeded(sender, args) {
    if (_destinationFile.get_exists() == true) {
        _destinationFile.checkOut();
    }

    _sourceFile.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, true);
    notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Copying file... ' +
                                            _sourceFile.get_serverRelativeUrl() + 
                                            ' to ' + _destinationlibUrl, true);

    _ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File copied successfully', false);

            //if (_destinationFile.get_exists() == true) {
            //_destinationFile.checkIn('Document Check-In',SP.CheckinType.majorCheckIn);
            //}

            // Redirect to Library B when complete
            window.location = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '/LibraryB/';
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error copying file', false);
            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
            alert('Error occured: ' + args.get_message());
        }
    );
}

// Delegate that is called when server operation is completed with errors.
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the file copying code here? Just to have the understanding how you are proceeding, may be then we could help you

Answer (score 2):

I used managed CSOM to complete the same task before.  You can find the code at http://wp.me/p23FqP-1U.  I am not good at JavaScript. Hopefully you can work out the JavaScript from my C# code.

Here is my C# code

```
public void CopySharePointDocument(string siteUrl, string srcUrl, string desinationUrl)
 {
     var relativeSrcUrl = srcUrl.Substring(srcUrl.IndexOf('/', 8));
     var relativeDestinationUrl = desinationUrl.Substring(desinationUrl.IndexOf('/', 8));
     File existFile = GetFile(siteUrl, relativeDestinationUrl);

     using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
     {
         ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domain);
         var site = ctx.Web;
         var sourceFile = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeSrcUrl);
         ctx.Load(sourceFile);
         ctx.ExecuteQuery();
         if (existFile!=null)
         {
             UpdateFile(ctx, relativeSrcUrl, relativeDestinationUrl);
         }
         else
         {
             sourceFile.CopyTo(desinationUrl, false);
         }
         ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     }
 }

 static private void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream destination)
 {
     byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
     int bytesRead;
     do
     {
         bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     } while (bytesRead != 0);
 }

 private void UpdateFile(ClientContext ctx, string relativeSrcUrl, string relativeDestinationUrl)
 {

     FileInformation fileInformation = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, relativeSrcUrl);
     using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         CopyStream(fileInformation.Stream, memoryStream);
         memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, relativeDestinationUrl, memoryStream, true);
     }
 }

 public File GetFile(string siteUrl, string relativeUrl)
 {
     using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
     {
         ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domain);
         var site = ctx.Web;
         var file = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl);
         try
         {
             ctx.Load(file);
             ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // this will throw exception if the file does not exist
             return file;
         }
         catch (ServerException ex)
         {
             if (ex.Message == "File Not Found.")
             {
                 return null;
             }
             throw;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for both copy and move:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var _ctx;
var _sourceFile;
var _destinationlibUrl;
var _destinationFile;
var siteUrl = '/sites/intestsite';
var targetListItem;
var itemId=12;

    $(document).ready(function () {


    $("#btnCopy").on("click", function(){

    CopyFile() ;
    })
});

function CopyFile() {
    _ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    // Get the Web site that is associated with the client context.
    this.web = _ctx.get_web();
    _ctx.load(this.web);

    // Returns the list with the specified title from the collection.
    this.sourceList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');
    _ctx.load(this.sourceList);

    // Get the list items being selected.
    //var selectedDocuments = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(_ctx);
    //this.currentItem = sourceList.getItemById(selectedDocuments[0].id);

    this.currentItem = sourceList.getItemById(itemId);
    _ctx.load(this.currentItem);

    // Get the file that is represented by the item from a document library.
    _sourceFile = this.currentItem.get_file();
    _ctx.load(_sourceFile);

    _ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

// Delegate that is called when the query completes successfully.
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {


    if (_sourceFile != null) {
        _destinationlibUrl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() +'/PageArchive/' + _sourceFile.get_name();
         alert('Now moving to: ' + _destinationlibUrl);

         //_sourceFile.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl, 1);
        _sourceFile.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, 1);

         notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Moving file ' + _sourceFile.get_serverRelativeUrl() + ' to ' + _destinationlibUrl, true);


        _ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File copied successfully', false);

            window.location = web.get_serverRelativeUrl();
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error copying file', false);
            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
            alert('Error occured: ' + args.get_message());
        }
    );

    }

}

// Delegate that is called when the destination file checkout completes successfully.


// Delegate that is called when server operation is completed with errors.
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code will work for copying items from one library to another library and it will also check in the file in the destination.

```
   function copyItem() {
     
     file=$("#filename").val();
     
            var binary = "";            
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetItem",
                        Url: "https://<source site>/"+sourcelibname+"/"+file,
                        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {                    
                        binary = $(xData.responseXML).find("Stream").text();                                       
                        $().SPServices({
                        operation: "CopyIntoItems",
                        SourceUrl: "https://<source site>/"+sourcelibname+"/"+file,
                        DestinationUrls: ["https://<source site>/<destination site>/"+destinationlibname+"/"+file],
                        Stream: binary,                        
                        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                            alert(file+" has been successfully published to Technet 1.");
                            updatemetadata();
                        },
                        error: function ajaxError(response) {
                            alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
            
            }
            
//****************************************************************************************************************
            
function updatemetadata()
{
var requestUri = "<source site>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+sourcelibname+"')/items?$select=LinkFilename,*&$Filter=substringof('"+file+"',FileRef)";


var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) 
    { 
        metadata =data.d.results[0];
        
            getid();
    },
        error: function ajaxError(response) {
        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
    }
});

}
//****************************************************************************************************************

function getid()
{
var requestUri = "https://<source site>/<destination site>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+destinationlibname+"')/items?$select=LinkFilename,*&$Filter=substringof('"+file+"',FileRef)";


var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) 
    {
        updatedata(data.d.results[0].ID);
            },
        error: function ajaxError(response) {
        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
    }
});

}
//****************************************************************************************************************

function updatedata(ID)
{


    var url = "https://<source site>/<destination site>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+destinationlibname+"')/Items('"+ID+"')";
        var data = {                            
     __metadata: { 'type': destinationid },
     
    
        'Title':metadata.Title,
        
        };
            $.ajax({
     url:url,
     type: "POST",
      headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),        
                        "X-Http-Method": "MERGE",
                        "IF-MATCH": "*"  
                        },
                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                success: function (data) 
                                { 
                                    //alert('success');
                                    CheckInFile();

                                },
                                error: function (error) 
                                {
                                    alert(error.responseText.split(":")[5].split("}")[0]);
                                }
                        }); 
                        

    
}

//****************************************************************************************************************

function CheckInFile() {
 

var ServerRelativeUrlofFile ="https://insight.cas.com/sites/content/technet/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/content/technet/CASDocuments1/"+file+"')";

    $.ajax
        ({

            url: ServerRelativeUrlofFile + "/CheckIn()",
            type: "POST",
            headers:
        {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert(file+" Published to technet successfully 2. ");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //alert(xhr.responseText);
                 alert(file+" Republished to technet successfully 3. ");
            }
        });
}
//****************************************************************************************************************
```