# How to get item id of copied file from SharePoint javascript api

Tags: javascript, document-library, sharepoint-server, jsom, copy-item

I want to copy multiple files from one Document Library to another with metadata and column values associated from the copied file to the destination file. I am using SharePoint 2013 JavaScript Client Object Model.
I referred to the code at this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/100327 link, but I am unable to get Item IDs of newly copied files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyTo` method don't return any values. Hence I believe you need to get newly created file as below

```
 _destinationlibUrl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() +'/PageArchive/' + _sourceFile.get_name();
 _sourceFile.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, 1);

 _ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function (sender, args) {
      var url = _destinationlibUrl .replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,'');    
      var newFile = _ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);   
      _ctx.load(newFile,'ListItemAllFields'); 
      _ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                  alert(newFile.get_id());
            }, 
            function () {
                  alert("Failed");
            }
       );
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        alert('Error occured: ' + args.get_message());
    }
```

Comment: The file is getting copied but giving error at---- alert(newFile.get_id());----
Error Message: Uncaught TypeError: newFile.get_id is not a function

Comment: the line alert(newFile.get_id()); should be replaced by alert(newFile.get_listItemAllFields().get_id());